# I have a MaterialUi Table wrapped within a Paper component. How can I add a minimize button to minimize my table or the Paper component?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-tables

I have a MaterialUi Table wrapped within a Paper component. How can I add a minimize button to minimize my table or the Paper component?This is my code:

```
<TableContainer component={Paper} style={{maxHeight:'inherit', maxWidth:'inherit', boxSizing:'border-box'}}>
              <Table size='small'>
                  <TableHead style={{
        backgroundColor: 'black'
      }}>
                      <TableRow>{headingsArray.map(val=><TableCell>{val}</TableCell>)}
                      </TableRow>
                  </TableHead>
                  <TableBody>
                  {
                    Object.entries(blueprint).map(([key,val]) =>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>{key}</TableCell>
                        {val.map((x)=><TableCell>{x}</TableCell>)}
                    </TableRow>
                    )
                  }
    
    
                  </TableBody>
              </Table>
          </TableContainer>
```

Answer (score 1):

For minimise functionality you could use MUI accordion component to handle it for you and put the table inside it:

```
<Accordion>
  <AccordionSummary
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    aria-controls="panel-content"
    id="panel-header"
  >
    <Typography className={classes.heading}>Accordion Heading</Typography>
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
    <TableContainer
      component={Paper}
      style={{
        maxHeight: 'inherit',
        maxWidth: 'inherit',
        boxSizing: 'border-box',
      }}
    >
      <Table size="small">
        <TableHead
          style={{
            backgroundColor: 'black',
          }}
        >
          <TableRow>
            {headingsArray.map((val) => (
              <TableCell>{val}</TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {Object.entries(blueprint).map(([key, val]) => (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell>{key}</TableCell>
              {val.map((x) => (
                <TableCell>{x}</TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-glitter-3pccn?file=/demo.js